# getting powerpivot to setup a lookup table for month names

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2010, lookup-tables, powerpivot

I have a MySQL DB and I fetch data from there via PowerPivot into a table.

[image]

Then I created a PivotTable from this table data.

[image]

Now the column month holds the month of the record as an index from 1 to 12. This doesn't look pleasing to the eye, hence I would like to replace the index with its respective month name.

Like "March" for 3.

Here comes the concept of the lookupt table into play. So I set up a lookup table for the month names in the sheet "Lookup-Tables".

[image]

I clicked the "create related table" button ...

[image]

... and next thing I see is the very month table in the PowerPivot window. The respective sheet I called "month names".

[image]

what is missing is the link of course:

[image]

As you can see I established a link between the original data table's column "month" with the lookup table's column "index".

but no matter if I refresh or even create a new PivotTable ... month still shows the index instead of the month name.

when I go back into the PivotTable I can select the lookup table's colum "index" which leads to a yellow message stating that "maybe the relationships should be freshly established". I click "do so" and next I see is a message that says that no relationship could be established!?

[image]

I don't get it?

My goal is pretty common sense and straight forward I think. If you have a different solution from using lookup tables ... maybe using DAX (which I don't know much about yet) ... that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Unselect the two red checkboxes highlighted below and select the green checkbox. Let me know if this solves your problem

[image: Checkboxes]

Comment: that is it ... how could I not get to this point? sometimes ... thanks anyway and the bounty is yours in 6 hours!

Comment: I know. You were almost there too!